# gtkmm 4: How to get X window ID from inside widget?

Tags: c++, x11, gtkmm, gtkmm4

In gtkmm 4, how can one get the X Window ID of type `XID` as defined in `X11/X.h`, from inside a class, that inherits from `Gtk::Widget`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all of them have one.

Those widgets that do will implement the [`GtkNative`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/GtkNative.html) interface, which provides the [`gtk_native_get_surface`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/GtkNative.html#gtk-native-get-surface) function, allowing you to obtain a [`GdkSurface`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/4.0/GdkSurface.html). In gtkmm, this will correspond to casting to to `Gtk::Native` and calling [`get_surface`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/4.0/classGtk_1_1Native.html#a646b2a7230a58cadf1570a26bf656dfd).

To obtain a `Window` handle from that, you can use the [`GDK_SURFACE_XID`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk4/4.0/gdk4-X-Window-System-Interaction.html#GDK-SURFACE-XID:CAPS) macro.  For that, I don’t think a C++ wrapper exists; you will have to call [`Gdk::Surface::gobj`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/4.0/classGdk_1_1Surface.html#aff13b400f3cbc06c3e7b0c254c05242d) to obtain a `GdkSurface *` and use the C API.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add two things to the accepted answer

1. It is of course important to check if `get_surface()` returned a valid nonzero object indeed. Otherwise get the ID after the Widget's `signal_realize()` is emitted, which is done after the widget is assigned to a surface. This can be achieved by overriding the default handler `on_realize()`
2. Instead of casting and calling `((Gtk::Native)this)->get_surface()` it is also possible to call like `get_native()->get_surface()`.

In conclusion do

```
void myWidget::on_realize() {
    // Call default handler
    Gtk::Widget::on_realize();
    XID x_window = GDK_SURFACE_XID(get_native()->get_surface()->gobj());
}
```

to get the X window ID as early as possible.